# NoneType erorr when calling .lower() method on annotated text

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, attributeerror, nonetype, stanza

I have annotated articles in a list (len=488), and I want to apply the `.lower()` method on the lemmas. I get the following error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`. Here's the code:

```
file = open("Guardian_Syria_text.csv", mode="r", encoding='utf-8-sig')
data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
file.close

pickle.dump(data, open('List.p', 'wb'))

stanza.download('en')
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en',
                      processors='tokenize,lemma,POS',
                      use_gpu=True)

data_list = pickle.load(open('List.p', 'rb'))
new_list = []

for article in data_list:
  a = nlp(str(article))
  new_list.append(a)
pickle.dump(new_list, open('Annotated.p', 'wb'))

annot_data = pickle.load(open('Annotated.p', 'rb'))
pos_tags = {'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADJ', 'ADV', 'X'}
lemmas = []

for article in annot_data:
  art_tokens = [w.text for s in article.sentences for w in s.words]
  art_lemmas = [w.lemma.lower() for s in article.sentences for w in s.words
                if w.upos in pos_tags]
  lemmas.append(art_lemmas)
```

I searched the variable `annot_data` for `None` (`print(annot_data is None)`), but it returned `False`.
I tried cleaning the variable like so `clean = [x for x in annot_data if x != None]`, but the length of the variable `clean` is the same as the old one (488), and the code gives me same error message using the new `clean` variable instead of the old `annot_data` one.

Where's the supposed NoneType and how can I avoid it?

Comment: `file.close` should be `file.close()`. Better yet, use `with`.

Comment: The error means that `w.lemma` is `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error refers to `w.lemma.lower()`, so the problem is that `w.lemma` is `None`, not that `article` is `None`.

You can check for this in the list comprehension.

```
  art_lemmas = [w.lemma.lower() for s in article.sentences for w in s.words
                if w.lemma is not None and w.upos in pos_tags]
```